# Automation steps not found

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to modify the comboBox values of the fields in the Automation Steps page. , but I cannot seem to be able to do it for all of them. Some of them are appearing disabled:

[image]

So I tried to make this change in the DB directly. However the graph is not public so I cannot identify the datamember definition.

I did identify however, the following  tables:
- AUStepCombo: includes the Values of the combo box. In this case I obtain all the records from the smartpanel

[image]

This table, however, does not include the description.

- AUCombo: includes the descriptions of the combobox, connected with AUStepCombo via the RowNbr field. 
  However, I noticed that the AUCombo table doesn't show all the values from the smartpanel. Only a subsection of the values from AUStepCombo. The fields disabled in the smartpanel, are the ones not inclued in this table.

[image]

Are these available in another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out CROpportunityProbability table. you will see the StageIDs in there.

Comment: Thank you! that was very helpful